# Difference between $\mathbb{E}({T_1T_2\mid T)}$ and $\mathbb{E}({T_1^2\mid T)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

The problem is the following:

> Let $(T_n)_{n>1}$ a succession of i.i.d.'s r.v with distribution $\exp(\lambda)$ and define $T=T_1+T_2+\cdots+T_n$
>
> a) Calculate the conditional distribution of $T_1\mid T$
>
> b) Calculate $\mathbb{E}(T_1\mid T)$

a) and b) are related and i got that for a) the distribution does not depend on the parameter $\lambda$ but only in the large of the sample and the distribution is a $Beta(1,n-1)$ times $T$**

But for the last two:

> c) $\mathbb{E}({T_1T_2\mid T)}$
>
> d) $\mathbb{E}({T_1^2\mid T)}$

Do they have to be equal? By i.i.d. I suppose both have to be equal but maybe there's a trick or something to obtain both or something like that.

Comment: c) is easy to get from d): write $T^2 = \mathbb{E}[T^2\mid T] = \mathbb{E}[(\sum T_i)^2\mid T] = n \mathbb{E}[T_1^2\mid T] + n(n-1) \mathbb{E}[T_1 T_2\mid T]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent, so the expectation of their product equals the product of their expectations.  However, they are **not** *conditionally* independent.

Think about their joint conditional distribution some more....

> $$\begin{align}f_{T_1,T_2\mid T}(x,y\mid z)=\dfrac{f_{T_1}(x)f_{T_2}(y)f_{T\mid T_1,T_2}(z\mid x,y)}{\int_0^{z-y}\int_0^{z-x-y} f_{T_1}(s)f_{T_2}(t)f_{T\mid T_1,T_2}(z\mid s,t)~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d s}\end{align}$$

---

$T_1$ and $T_1$ are dependent (being surely equal), so the expectation of the square is *not* the square of the expectation.

Rather, since you have found the conditional distribution, use that : $$\mathsf E(T_1^2\mid T)=\mathsf{Var}(T_1\mid T)+\mathsf E^2(T_1\mid T)$$